# Problem with summ formula when i use a for loop in main method

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, recursion, sum

this is my code for a recursive function of a summation. The function works perfectly well, but when I use a for loop in main method, to give out all the sums untill ten,  the system stops working and I have no explanation for it. When I remove the foor loop, the system is perfectly fine again.  The error I get is the following : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int summ(int x) {
    if(x == 1)

    {
        return 1;
    }

    else {
        return summ(x - 1) + x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int const n = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)

    {
        cout << summ(i) << " " << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *The function works perfectly well* - For what inputs?  Note that your function recurses forever (or at least until `x` wraps all the way around) when `x <= 0`.  Maybe the stop condition of `summ` should be `if(x <= 1)`?

Comment: Try changing `int i = 0;` to `int i = 1;`

Comment: Arthur: This is still listed as an unanswered question. Didn't any of the answers help you to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The recursive function does not process correctly the argument when it is equal to zero.

Rewrite the function the following way

```
unsigned long long summ( unsigned int x ) 
{
    return x == 0 ? 0 : x + summ( x - 1 );
}
```

There is no sense to declare the parameter as having a signed integer type if you are going to calculate a sum of non-negative numbers.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long summ( unsigned int x ) 
{
    return x == 0 ? 0 : x + summ( x - 1 );
}

int main() 
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << summ( i ) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first iteration `i = 0` which means that `summ` will miss your termination criteria (`if(x == 1)`). It'll then recurse `summ(x-1)` and continue down recursing until the stack overflows.